# Viterbi Algorithm: initial state with ONE probability

Tags: probability-theory, hidden-markov-models

The [Viterbi Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) can be used to calculate the most likely path, based on observations in a Hidden Markov Model.

Using the same notations as Wikipedia, "each element `T1[i, j]` of `T1` stores the probability of the most likely path so far `X = (x[1] , x[2] , ... , x[j])`  with `x[j] = s[i]` that generates `Y = (y[1] , y[2] , ... , y[j])`.

Now suppose, that the initial distribution $\pi$ is such that for one state the probability is `1` (let's call it state `K`), and for all other states it is `0`. Also, let's say that in the emission matrix `B` all elements are strongly between 0 and 1 (i.e. `0 < B[i, j] < 1` for all `i` and `j`.

In this way `0 < T[K,1] < 1` and for all other states `T[i,1] = 1`.

**Problem**:
For me, the part `T[K,1] < 1` feels intuitively wrong. How can it be, that the first state is `K`, with probability `1`, still the most likely path contains it with probability less than `1`?

I understand that the reason must be something like: "There are more different paths. One where the first state is `K`, and the first observation is `y1`. One, where the first state is `K`, and the observation is `y2`. Etc.".

However, it is also true, that "no matter what the observation is, the first state is `K` with probability `1`".

**Question**: What is the explanation for this (seeming) contradiction? (The best would be if it is "intuitive".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia is wrong.  That's not what $T_1$ stores.  Rather, $T_1$ stores the likelihood of a path... namely, the likelihood of the path that has the highest likelihood.  What's the likelihood of a path $\hat{X}$?  It is the probability of generating the output sequence $Y$ given that you followed the path $\hat{X}$, i.e., the probability $P(Y | \hat{X})$.  Note that this is *not* the same as $P(\hat{X} | Y)$.

The probability $P(Y | \hat{X})$ might be less than 1, even if we're certain that $\hat{X}$ was the path that was followed.  In particular, you can have $P(Y | \hat{X}) < 1$ even if $P(\hat{X}) = 1$.  This can happen, for example, if there are multiple possible output sequences that could arise when following the path $\hat{X}$.

As usual, Wikipedia is not a primary source.  Don't use Wikipedia as your only source for learning new material.  It is helpful as a summary, but when you find something in Wikipedia that is confusing or that doesn't make sense, go to a primary source -- e.g., a highly reputed textbook.  Wikipedia does have errors, poor writing, gaps in its explanation, and so on, so it is not a substitute for a high-quality primary source.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up quite a bit. I think the key is that `T` stores `P(Y|X^)` and *not* `P(X)` (as I thought originally) neither `P(X|Y)`.